# C# - Condition which is true if 3/9 buttons have the same text

Tags: c#, button, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm trying to make a basic noughts and crosses game in c#.
So far I've made the grid using buttons which's text changes when it is pressed depending which player's turn it is.
The part which I am stuck on is checking if any of the players has won, I've written this however it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button9.Text == "X")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Player", player_turntxt.Text + " wins");
            Application.Restart();
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Player_Turn = Convert.ToInt32(player_turntxt.Text);
        if (Player_Turn == 1)
        {
            button1.Text = "X";
            player_turntxt.Text = "2";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "O";
            player_turntxt.Text = "1";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }
```

(The Application.Restart(); is just a temporary method of checking if it works.)
This is just one of 8 statements which I'll have to make as conditions for victory, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Update:

```
        public void CheckForWinner(int x)
    {

        if (button1.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button9.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button3.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button7.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button1.Text == "X" && button4.Text == "X" && button7.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button2.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button8.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button3.Text == "X" && button6.Text == "X" && button9.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button1.Text == "X" && button2.Text == "X" && button3.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button4.Text == "X" && button5.Text == "X" && button6.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (button7.Text == "X" && button8.Text == "X" && button9.Text == "X")
        {
            x = 1;
        }



        if (button1.Text == "O" && button5.Text == "O" && button9.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button3.Text == "O" && button5.Text == "O" && button7.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button1.Text == "O" && button4.Text == "O" && button7.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button2.Text == "O" && button5.Text == "O" && button8.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button3.Text == "O" && button6.Text == "O" && button9.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button1.Text == "O" && button2.Text == "O" && button3.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button4.Text == "O" && button5.Text == "O" && button6.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (button7.Text == "O" && button8.Text == "O" && button9.Text == "O")
        {
            x = 2;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What happens when you debug?

Comment: Your check is when the form loads, not after each turn

Comment: You should create a method to check if any player has won, and run it at the end of everyone of your "button clicks".

Comment: That's it! It's because I'm doing it at the start of the program... Thank you :)

Comment: The code is hardly testable/maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a method to check if any player has won, and run it at the end of everyone of your "button clicks".

I algo suggest you to remove the "return"'s from your button clicks. They can introduce unexpected behaviors sometimes, like ending the function before you execute the line of code that calls the method to check if someone has won.

Something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Player_Turn = Convert.ToInt32(player_turntxt.Text);
        if (Player_Turn == 1)
        {
            button1.Text = "X";
            player_turntxt.Text = "2";
            button1.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "O";
            player_turntxt.Text = "1";
            button1.Enabled = false;

        }

CheckIfSomeoneHasWon();
}
```

Let's discuss the implementation of CheckIfSomeoneHasWon. I figure that there are several ways of doing it. We could create a bidimensional array with the values of the buttons, and iterate it. In fact, I will do it that way. Your way works too, but we would have to write a lot. This is what I came up with:

```
static readonly string _player1_symbol = "X";
        static readonly string _player2_symbol = "O";

 static void CheckIfSomeoneHasWon()
        {
            string[,] userChoices = BuildUserChoices();

            string winner = CheckWhoWon(userChoices);

            if (winner != null)
            {
                // Somebody won! Display message and start over
            }
        }

        private static string CheckWhoWon(string[,] values)
        {
            // Horizontal checks
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (values[i, 0] == values[i, 1] && values[i, 1] == values[i, 2])
                {
                    return (values[i, 0] == _player1_symbol) ? "player 1" : "player 2";
                }
            }

            // Vertical checks
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (values[0, i] == values[1, i] && values[1,i] == values[2,i])
                {
                    return (values[i, 0] == _player1_symbol) ? "player 1" : "player 2";
                }
            }

            // Diagonal checks
            if (values[0, 0] == values[1, 1] && values[1, 1] == values[2, 2])
            {
                return (values[0, 0] == _player1_symbol) ? "player 1" : "player 2";
            }

            if (values[0, 2] == values[1, 1] && values[1, 1] == values[2, 0])
            {
                return (values[1, 1] == _player1_symbol) ? "player 1" : "player 2";
            }
            // No one has won yet
            return null;
        }

        private static string[,] BuildUserChoices()
        {
            var values = new string[3, 3];
            values[0, 0] = button1.Text;
            values[0, 1] = button2.Text;
            values[0, 2] = button3.Text;
// and so on...
            // If a button has not been click, they must have a unique text, like a number

            return values;
        }
```

Comment: What parameter would I give to the method tho?

Comment: I would not send any parameters. You only need to check the text of the buttons. Need help with the implementation?

Comment: Please yeah... I'll update my question with what I did so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a player wins after each turn. Right now you are checking it once, after the form loaded.